# LVM volume silently fails to mount

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, lvm

In my server I have one NVMe SSD and two plain old 4TB HDDs which are used for mass data storage. During setup of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I liked the idea of keeping both HDDs separate and did not set up LVM. Later I found that one disk fills up a lot faster than the other, so I decided to set up LVM after the fact.

I wiped disk 2 and created a new GPT partition table using fdisk. Then I added a new partition that takes up the whole disk and set the partition type to Linux LVM.

```
root@server:/# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): g
Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: AEF8BBF3-526D-394C-A0A7-5852FF661F95).

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1):
First sector (2048-7814037134, default 2048):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-7814037134, default 7814037134):

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 3.7 TiB.

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Partition type (type L to list all types): 31
Changed type of partition 'Linux filesystem' to 'Linux LVM'.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Then I created a physical volume, a volume group and a logical volume. I set the logical volume to be active and created a BTRFS file system on it.

```
root@server:/# pvcreate /dev/sdb1
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb1" successfully created.

root@server:/# vgcreate storage /dev/sdb1
  Volume group "storage" successfully created

root@server:/# lvcreate -n downloads -L 3.63TB storage
  Rounding up size to full physical extent 3.63 TiB
  Logical volume "downloads" created.

root@server:/# lvchange -ay /dev/storage/downloads

root@server:/# mkfs.btrfs /dev/storage/downloads
btrfs-progs v5.4.1
See http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org for more information.

Label:              (null)
UUID:               ba46d3c4-38a2-4122-9f58-48bc0546a49d
Node size:          16384
Sector size:        4096
Filesystem size:    3.63TiB
Block group profiles:
  Data:             single            8.00MiB
  Metadata:         DUP               1.00GiB
  System:           DUP               8.00MiB
SSD detected:       no
Incompat features:  extref, skinny-metadata
Checksum:           crc32c
Number of devices:  1
Devices:
   ID        SIZE  PATH
    1     3.63TiB  /dev/storage/downloads
```

At this point everything looks good and ready to be used.

```
root@server:/# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                   7:0    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2253
loop1                   7:1    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1242
loop2                   7:2    0  73.1M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21902
sda                     8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sda1                  8:1    0   3.7T  0 part /mnt/data1
sdb                     8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   3.7T  0 part
  └─storage-downloads 253:0    0   3.6T  0 lvm
nvme0n1               259:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0 476.4G  0 part /

root@server:/# blkid -o list
device              fs_type   label      mount point             UUID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/nvme0n1p1      vfat                 /boot/efi               DC44-3B2F
/dev/nvme0n1p2      btrfs                (in use)                d0be6aed-8d84-495e-b69e-fc46f2700254
/dev/sda1           btrfs                (in use)                17316c71-d190-456f-a3de-ff40a8ca2c3c
/dev/loop0          squashfs             /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop1          squashfs             /snap/core20/1242
/dev/loop2          squashfs             /snap/lxd/21902
/dev/sdb1           LVM2_member          (in use)                6cZbcI-egPH-butU-DN2Z-fQre-R8l0-z6CKkZ
/dev/mapper/storage-downloads
                    btrfs                (not mounted)           ba46d3c4-38a2-4122-9f58-48bc0546a49d
```

I updated `/etc/fstab` to include the new partition and list the mount point.

```sh
root@server:/# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d0be6aed-8d84-495e-b69e-fc46f2700254 / btrfs defaults 0 0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/DC44-3B2F /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0

# 4TB HDDs
UUID=17316c71-d190-456f-a3de-ff40a8ca2c3c /mnt/data1 btrfs defaults 0 0
#UUID=7bba47ee-4053-45e1-bf53-03892a8eb474 /mnt/data2 btrfs defaults 0 0  # Pre-LVM partition
UUID=ba46d3c4-38a2-4122-9f58-48bc0546a49d /mnt/data2 btrfs defaults 0 0
```

Next, I mount the new logical volume:

```
root@server:/# mount /mnt/data2
```

No error, so it all looks good, however it still shows as not mounted.

```
root@server:/# blkid -o list
device              fs_type   label      mount point             UUID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/nvme0n1p1      vfat                 /boot/efi               DC44-3B2F
/dev/nvme0n1p2      btrfs                (in use)                d0be6aed-8d84-495e-b69e-fc46f2700254
/dev/sda1           btrfs                (in use)                17316c71-d190-456f-a3de-ff40a8ca2c3c
/dev/loop0          squashfs             /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop1          squashfs             /snap/core20/1242
/dev/loop2          squashfs             /snap/lxd/21902
/dev/sdb1           LVM2_member          (in use)                6cZbcI-egPH-butU-DN2Z-fQre-R8l0-z6CKkZ
/dev/mapper/storage-downloads
                    btrfs                (not mounted)           ba46d3c4-38a2-4122-9f58-48bc0546a49d
```

Also, any data I write to it ends up on the `/dev/nvme0n1p2` disk, since `/mnt` is on `/`, which is where the SSD is mounted, but not the newly created logical volume.

What is it I am missing?

EDIT:

With the help of Tom Yan's comment I managed to find an error in the systemd logs.

```
root@server:/# journalctl -b -e
Jan 02 13:08:25 server kernel: BTRFS info (device dm-0): flagging fs with big metadata feature
Jan 02 13:08:25 server kernel: BTRFS info (device dm-0): disk space caching is enabled
Jan 02 13:08:25 server kernel: BTRFS info (device dm-0): has skinny extents
Jan 02 13:08:25 server systemd[1]: mnt-data2.mount: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7bba47ee\x2d4053\x2d45e1\x2dbf53\x2d03892a8eb474.device. Stopping, too.
Jan 02 13:08:25 server systemd[1]: Unmounting /mnt/data2...
Jan 02 13:08:25 server systemd[150969]: mnt-data2.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 02 13:08:25 server systemd[1]: mnt-data2.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 02 13:08:25 server systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/data2.
```

A simple `systemctl daemon-reload` fixed the issue: afterwards the mount worked as expected and the logs are clean.

```
root@server:/# journalctl -b -e
Jan 02 13:14:14 server systemd[150969]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-1eb6b8d67787d43d173426f8c658b027cfd8667aa520c430365c20b0b383d121-runc.WYdXc6.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 02 13:14:14 server systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-1eb6b8d67787d43d173426f8c658b027cfd8667aa520c430365c20b0b383d121-runc.WYdXc6.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 02 13:14:44 server systemd[150969]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-1eb6b8d67787d43d173426f8c658b027cfd8667aa520c430365c20b0b383d121-runc.WTnqMK.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 02 13:14:44 server systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-1eb6b8d67787d43d173426f8c658b027cfd8667aa520c430365c20b0b383d121-runc.WTnqMK.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 02 13:14:55 server kernel: BTRFS info (device dm-0): flagging fs with big metadata feature
Jan 02 13:14:55 server kernel: BTRFS info (device dm-0): disk space caching is enabled
Jan 02 13:14:55 server kernel: BTRFS info (device dm-0): has skinny extents
```

Comment: Have you try to set in `/etc/fstab` `/dev/mapper/storage-downloads` instead of `UUID=ba46d3c4-38a2-4122-9f58-48bc0546a49d`?

Comment: I faintly remember that there was a systemd bug that could make mounting fail silently (or, the filesystem gets unmounted automatically right away). You may check `dmesg` and/or `journalctl -b -e` to see if there were relevant logs. Also try `systemctl daemon-reload` or even, the reboot "magic".

Comment: @TomYan that `systemctl daemon-reload` did indeed do the trick. I updated my question with the relevant logs. If you post your comment as an answer I can mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be due to a flaw/bug in the particular version of systemd, which causes the filesystem on a newly created LV to be unmounted right away when the user attempts to mount it, and apparently it can be worked around by running:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

which causes the state(s) of relevant unit(s) in the systemd process to be updated and hence addresses the problem.